# Generar números aleatorios en C

Tags: c

He estado intentado con este código generar dos números al azar entre 1 y 100 pero no me salen y se generan de manera que no me cuadra.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, cualquiera, X, Y;

    srand(time(NULL));
    scanf("%d",&n);

     for (i = 0; i < n; i ++)
        {
            cualquiera = X+(int)(((Y-X+1.0)*rand())/(RAND_MAX+1.0));
            printf("%d ", cualquiera);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Prodias explicar que quiere decir que no te cuadran? da algun error? o que pasa?

Comment: Igual aca hay un problema muy grave, y es que X e Y no estan definidos, y por lo tanto tienen basura

Comment: Yo prefiero el termino que usaba un profesor: Tienen valores silvestres de memoria.

Comment: @abrahamhs que quiere decir "Tienen valores silvestres de memoria " ?

Comment: que tienen basura

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 

//Generar numerosAletorios
void numerosAletorios(int min, int max, int cant) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < cant; i++) { 
        int num = (rand() % 
           (max - min + 1)) + min; 
        printf("%d ", num); 
    } 
} 


int main() 
{ 
    int min = 1, max = 100, cant = 2; 

    numerosAletorios(min, max, cant); 

    return 0; 
}
```

ahora el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero te sirva y suerte..!!